# Segmentation fault (core dumped) for PCL example_nurbs_fitting_curve2d

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am trying to run the point cloud library [example_nurbs_fitting_curve2d.cpp](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/examples/surface/example_nurbs_fitting_curve2d.cpp) using [curve2d.pcd](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/test/curve2d.pcd) file as data points on which curve is to be fit. After successfully building the project i tried to run the code from build folder using        `$ ./example_nurbs_fitting_curve2d curve2d.pcd`. this curve2d.pcd file is in the build folder of the project. It appeared as Curve2d.pcd started loading like

> loading curve2d.pcd

But then following error occured

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Currently, i have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed, I am not sure if its some kind of programming error or am I missing something? Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Using ubuntu 16.04, I tried debugging every line of code but couldn't find the reason of "Segmentation fault". Then i changed my Ubuntu version to 14.04 and reinstalled pcl 1.7.2. No segmentation fault error occurred. It generates output as expected.

I guess, its the updated version of c++ in ubuntu 16.04 which is not compatible with pcl versions.